# How do i round down float number?

Tags: c

I have number 0.2289 and i want round down it to make 0.2200
Can i help pls ?

i tried printf(%.2f/n) but it rounds it up

Comment: I guess you could multiply it by 100.0f, then take the floorf() of that, then divide by 100.0f.

Comment: Beware that while you can certainly do this, after you're done you are likely to end up with a number like 0.2199999988 or 0.22000000000000000111, because 0.22 cannot be represented exactly in binary.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will not have an exact representation of the rounded number but you can try to:

```
double roundDown2(const double number)
{
    return floor(number * 100) / 100;
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("%.20f\n", roundDown2( 0.2289));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5a9EshWM1